# Ads for iPhone and Android?

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

Can someone explain to me how implementing ads works in libGDX, Android and iPhone?
Regarding a libGdx game: If I want to release my game for both Android and iPhone, can I use the same ad services or for each their own?
Since I don't have any knowledge about how ads work, how can one try and make a living from ads, where I need to register in order to create an account that'll manage my earnings and so on... can someone go through the trouble of explaining everything to me?

P.S I don't have any delusions of FB's success, only looks to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself use AdMob.

[Here is how it works in a nutshell](http://www.google.com/ads/admob/monetize.html)

[And here is the implementation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx)